# Grouping duplicate rows and calculating effective and end dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, duplicates

As per the attached sample, I have data of repeated rows with different date values. I would like to combine the duplicate records to reduce the number of rows and at the same time would like to calculate the end date of record.
“CountryCode” column should be used to combine the records and value changes in “CountryRiskLevel” or “RegionRiskLevel” columns should be used to define the start and end date ranges.
Database - SQL Server.

[image]

Comment: your dbmas name please

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin  - SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, I used slightly different sample data, but query will work for you as well:

```
;with SampleData as(
    select 1 CountryCode,
           1 RegionCode,
           5 CountryRiskLevel, 
           5 RegionRiskLevel, 
           CONVERT(date, '2018-01-01') EffectiveDate
    union all
    select 1,1,5,5,CONVERT(date, '2018-01-02')
    union all
    select 1,1,5,5,CONVERT(date, '2018-01-03')
    union all
    select 1,1,5,5,CONVERT(date, '2018-01-04')
    union all
    select 1,1,2,2,CONVERT(date, '2018-01-05')
    union all
    select 1,1,5,5,CONVERT(date, '2018-01-06')
    union all
    select 1,1,5,5,CONVERT(date, '2018-01-07')
    union all
    select 1,1,5,3,CONVERT(date, '2018-01-08')
    union all
    select 1,1,5,5,CONVERT(date, '2018-01-09')
    union all
    select 1,1,5,5,CONVERT(date, '2018-01-10')
    union all
    select 1,1,5,5,CONVERT(date, '2018-01-11')
)

select CountryCode,
       RegionCode,
       CountryRiskLevel,
       RegionRiskLevel,
       MIN(effectiveDate) EffecticeStartDate,
       case when MAX(effectiveDate) = MIN(effectiveDate) then MAX(dt) else MAX(effectiveDate) end EffectiveEndDate
from (
    select *,
          ROW_NUMBER() over  (partition by CountryCode, RegionCode, CountryRiskLevel, RegionRiskLevel order by EffectiveDate) rn1,
          ROW_NUMBER() over  (order by EffectiveDate) rn2,
          case when COUNT(*) over (partition by countrycode, RegionCode, CountryRiskLevel, RegionRiskLevel) = 1 
               then LEAD(effectivedate) over (order by effectivedate) end dt
    from SampleData
) a group by CountryCode, RegionCode, CountryRiskLevel, RegionRiskLevel, rn2 - rn1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Works perfect. I have to slightly modify the script to get it work on whole lot of data. Thanks again,